# Filter a dataframe based specific condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below

df:

```
ID     Age_days    N_30     N_31_90     N_91_180      N_181_365   Group
1      201         60       15          30            40          Good
2      20          2        15          5             20          Normal
3      10          4        0           0             0           Normal
4      100         0        0           0             80          Normal
5      600         0        6           5             60          Good
6      800         0        0           15            0           Good
7      500         10       10          30            40          Normal     
8      200         0        0           0             100         Good
9      500         0        0           0             20          Normal
10     80          0        12          0             20          Normal
```

where

```
N_30 - Number of transactions in last 30 days
N_31_90 - Number of transactions in last 31 to 90 days and so on.

Conditions for filtering

      If Age_days is less than 30, N_31_90, N_91_180, N_181_365 should be 0.
      If Age_days is less than 90, N_91_180, N_181_365 should be 0.
      If Age_days is less than 180, N_181_365 should be 0.
```

But in the above data there are some rows where Age_days is less and transacted before.
I would like to filter such rows.

Expected output:

```
ID     Age_days    N_30     N_31_90     N_91_180      N_181_365   Group
2      20          2        15          5             20          Normal
4      100         0        0           0             80          Normal
10     80          0        12          0             20          Normal
```

Comment: "But in the above data there are some rows where Age_days is less and transacted before." Less than what ?

Comment: @CygnusX Can you please point out such rows? I think there are only 3 rows as I shown.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. I am asking a question about your original sentence :  "...where Age_days is less [than ?] and transacted before."  in order to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CygnusX For example if Age_days less than 30, then the number of transactions between 31 to 90 days back should be 0 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Boolean Mask` to filter conditions:

```
m1 = (df['Age_days'] <= 30) & ((df['N_31_90'] !=0) | (df['N_91_180'] !=0) | (df['N_181_365'] !=0))
m2 = (df['Age_days'] <= 90) & ((df['N_91_180'] !=0) | (df['N_181_365'] !=0))
m3 = (df['Age_days'] <= 180) & (df['N_181_365'] !=0)

print(df[m1|m2|m3])
```

m1 is the boolean mask for the invalid condition where `Age_days` is `<= 30` while there are non-zero values for transactions performed more than 30 days ago.  Similarly for m2 and m3.

Then we do a Boolean Or with `m1|m2|m3` in `df[m1|m2|m3]` to filter the rows with any one of the 3 invalid conditions.

Output:

```
   ID  Age_days  N_30  N_31_90  N_91_180  N_181_365   Group
1   2        20     2       15         5         20  Normal
3   4       100     0        0         0         80  Normal
9  10        80     0       12         0         20  Normal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one liner:

```py
import numpy as np
df2 = df.loc[df['Age_days'] < np.maximum(np.maximum((df['N_31_90'] > 0) * 31 , (df['N_91_180'] > 0) * 91), (df['N_181_365'] > 0) * 181)]
```